# Enable wireless networking by default

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04

Every time I restart/boot I have to right click the wireless icon again and click enable wireless, is there any way to have it enable wireless by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the default gnome nm-applet for networking the following will work when put as a startup application

```
nmcli nm wifi on
```